# CSS not being applied

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I've set a class on the `body` tag, called `container` and then in my CSS, I've tried using both `body.container` and simply `.container.` and yet whatever happens them image is not shown as the body background.

The browsers show clearly in their inspector that it isn't being applied. Weirdly, in Firefox, it shows a red dot next to the beginning of the rule which suggest there's something wrong and you can delete this dot, which makes the rule work and apply correctly.

I'm actually writing pre-processed SASS which is pre-compiled by Rails and weirdly again, running locally where it's compiled on the fly rather than pre-compiled, it works...

Here's a short snippet from the original SCSS file:

```
body.container {
  background: url('background.jpg');
  background-size: auto 110%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: "Tahoma";

  .personalization_box {
    position: absolute;
  }
...
}
```

And here's a snippet of the output CSS:
`#safari_rememberDiv{width:0px;height:0px;display:none}body.container{background:‌​url("background.jpg");background-size:auto 110%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;font-family:"Tahoma‌​"}body.container .personalization_box{position:absolute;top:5%;width:80%;left:10%;height:90%;bord‌​er-radius:15px;border:2px solid #5B5B5B;background-color:#FFF;overflow:hidden}`

I get the following error on CSS validation:
`#safari_rememberDiv    Lexical error at line 1, column 1010. Encountered: "\ufeff" (65279), after : "" }body.container{background:url("background.jpg");background-size:auto 110%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;font-family:"Tahoma"}`

[It's all on one line because it's generated by Rails that way, I can split it into multiple lines for clarity if that helps].

Comment: Are you purposely not closing the body.container bracket?

Comment: Your Sass is irrelevant, post the compiled CSS/Markup only.  There needs to be enough code here to reproduce a problem.

Comment: @Geoffrey It's correct in the code.

Comment: @cimmanon Here's a snippet of the CSS output: `safari_rememberDiv{width:0px;height:0px;display:none}body.container{background:url("background.jpg");background-size:auto 110%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;font-family:"Tahoma"}body.container .personalization_box{position:absolute;top:5%;width:80%;left:10%;height:90%;border-radius:15px;border:2px solid #5B5B5B;background-color:#FFF;overflow:hidden}`

Comment: are you importing this css file?

Comment: Is the image actually at that link?

Comment: Does your CSS validate?  Because it looks like you have some hidden characters injected in there.

Comment: @cimmanon Actually, no - surprising...
I get this:

`#safari_rememberDiv Lexical error at line 1, column 1010. Encountered: "\ufeff" (65279), after : "" }body.container{background:url("background.jpg");background-size:auto 110%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;font-family:"Tahoma"}`

Can you help?

Comment: @Patosai Yes, it is.

Comment: Are you running any sort of post processor on your CSS (concatenator, compressor, autoprefixer, etc)?  Sass shouldn't be generating invalid output like that.

Comment: @cimmanon I've just posted my solution which I found. It was generated by SASS, I believe - I don't have any other special post-processor running on my CSS. Anyway, it was down to file encoding and certain characters specifically: “ ” - they weren't used as quotes - they were used as a content property, but the encoding discrepancy between the files caused a UTF-8 BOM output which broke the file.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue and found the cause of the issue.

The two different .scss files pre-processed by SASS within Rails were in different character encodings, which led the pre-compiler to insert a UTF-8 BOM, the red dot, described by `\ufeff`. By changing the file encoding of this file to ISO-8859-1 (matching the other file) and hence removing some special quote marks later in my CSS (which were inserted using `element::before` and `content:`), I was able to resolve the issue.